# What are the possible way to handle TypeError Cannot read property 'something' of null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, replace, web-developer-toolbar

What are the possible ways to handle this in Reactjs?

```
TypeError
Cannot read property 'something' of null
```

Comment: The way to handle it, is not to do it. What do you expect to read from a null value? If, instead, you're trying to read from a *nullable* value (which is possibly null, not definitely null) - you use [optional chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139078/null-safe-property-access-and-conditional-assignment-in-es6-2015)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003884/how-do-i-check-for-null-values-in-javascript
This may answer your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531204/best-way-to-handle-null-values-in-reactjs this me a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1- Always check for being `null`:

```js
let blah;

if (obj) {
  blah = obj.something;
}
```

2- Use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
const blah = obj?.something;
```

From the docs:

> The ?. operator functions similarly to the . chaining operator, except
> that instead of causing an error if a reference is nullish (null or
> undefined), the expression short-circuits with a return value of
> undefined.

Comment: can I use this way to handle 
`blocks = blocks.something;` 
**if this gives something of null**
`blocks = blocks &&  blocks.something;`

Comment: @AmanAnku Yes that is also correct. But it's better to use another variable name for it: `const blockSomething = blocks && blocks.something`. But using optional chaining is the safest method.